# ASP Custom Validator error stays even after page refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, customvalidator

```cs
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
 
    }
    protected void cusCustom_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        var dropDownValue = drpState.SelectedItem.Text;
        if (dropDownValue == ""  && args.Value.Length < 1  )
        {
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
        else
        {
            args.IsValid = true;
        }
    }
----------------------------------------
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpState" runat="server" CausesValidation="True">
<asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="IL">Illinois</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="IN">Indiana</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="IA">Iowa</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtRegion"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        
    
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit"  ValidationGroup="test" auto Text="Submit" OnClientClick=" validateFields()" runat="server" />
    <asp:CustomValidator ValidationGroup="test" ID="CustomValidator" OnServerValidate="cusCustom_ServerValidate"
                    ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Please fill all fields." ValidateEmptyText ="true" 
                    ControlToValidate="txtRegion" runat="server">
                </asp:CustomValidator>
```

I have two fields textbox and drop down and after that I have asp custom validator when both fields are empty and I try to submit that it fire error. But the error still shows after page refresh how can I remove it?

Comment: What Error did you get exactly?

Comment: Also I think you forgot to specify the type that you want to be deserialized. it is in the angle brackets shown in this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

Comment: Why are you **re-serializing** that JSON? And why are you using `JavaScriptSerializer` (which is very, very old) instead of `JsonConvert` or `System.Text.Json`? ...and why are you using `WebClient`? There's a _lot_ of code-smells going on here...

Comment: It is from diffrent source so no type. Has to be generic

Comment: @SanmeetSingh That's not what "generic" means in the context of C#.

Comment: It is a webform and cannot use Newtonsoft libraries

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249503/discussion-between-sanmeet-singh-and-dai).

Comment: Im getting this in result {"Distance":0.0,"BookingLink":null,"Images":null,"HotelID":105304,"Name":"Hyatt Regency Century Plaza","AirportCode":}
want to extract the Name

Comment: @SanmeetSingh The error `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'` means in essence that your deserialized object is not a list/array. Try accessing the `Name` property using the dot notation `results.name`. I would strongly suggest you put a breakpoint and examine the object type you're getting back. Switch to [NewtonJason](https://www.newtonsoft.com/) or `System.Text.Json` or `JsonConvert` as suggested.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should create a dummy class that contains the names you want to de-serialze. You only need to put those properties in the dummy class you actually want to use and not all of them
e. g.

```cs
public DummyClass {
  public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

and then you need to adapt your code in these lines:

```cs
var result = jsonSerialization.DeserializeObject<DummyClass>(res);
MyLiteral.Text = result.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void Main()
{
    // Using Newtonsoft.Json
    var result = " {\"Distance\":0.0,\"BookingLink\":null,\"Images\":null,\"HotelID\":105304,\"Name\":\"Hyatt Regency Century Plaza\",\"AirportCode\": \"\"}";
    var hotel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Hotel>(result);
    Console.WriteLine(hotel.Name);
}

// Create the object class structure based on your JSON string results
public class Hotel
{
    public double Distance { get; set; }
    public string BookingLink { get; set; }
    public object Images { get; set; }
    public int HotelID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string AirportCode { get; set; }
}
```